# Using react-highcharts, trying to update the xAxis categories values, but it doesn't, it keeps the values in my config variable.

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

As stated above, I can't seem to get the categories to re-render when I am using the react-highchart library. I seem to be able to set the data of the chart values but I can't change the values of the xAxis categories, any help is appreciated. I am also rendering the highcharts in the render method.

**Code of config**

```
const config = {
  /* HighchartsConfig */

title: {
    text: ''
},

xAxis: {
    tickLength: 75,
    categories: [month1, month2, month3, month4],
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize:'13px'

      },
      formatter: function(){

      return '<span style="margin-right: 2.5px">' + this.chart.series[0].options.stack + '</span><span>' + this.chart.series[1].options.stack + 
      '</span><br /><div style="text-align:center"> <br />' + this.value + '</div> '
    },    
    useHTML: true
  } 
},

yAxis: [{ //--- Primary yAxis
  title: {
      text: 'Bugs, Questions And Enhancements'
  }
}, { //--- Secondary yAxis
  title: {
      text: 'Total Open'
  },
  opposite: true
}],

tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
            'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        allowPointSelect: false,

    },


},
legend: {
  events: {
    legendItemClick: function () {

       return false; 
       // <== returning false will cancel the default action
        }
    },
      itemStyle: {

          fontSize: '17px'
      }
},
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
series: 
[{
    yAxis: 0,
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Bug',
    color: '#1E90FF',
    stack: 'Open'

},
 {
    yAxis: 0,
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Bug',
    color: '#1E90FF',
    showInLegend: false,
    stack: 'Closed'
}, 
{
  yAxis: 0,
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Question',
  color: '#DC143C',
  stack: 'Open'
}, 
{
  yAxis: 0,
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Question',
  color: '#DC143C',
  showInLegend: false,
  stack: 'Closed'
},
{
  yAxis: 0,
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Enhancement',
  color: '#32CD32',
  stack: 'Open'
},
{ 
  yAxis: 0,
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Enhancement',
  color: '#32CD32',
  showInLegend: false,
  stack: 'Closed'
},{
    yAxis: 1,
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Total Open',
    color: '#2C2727',
    lineWidth: 4.5,
    animation: false,
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }

 ]};
```

**Code setting the categories not working**

```
 if(this.state.live == 0)
    {
       let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
       chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D']);
                              chart.redraw();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts now has Axis.update() functionality. Maybe something like this would solve:

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({categories:['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D']});
```

Comment: I have reduced to what might be perceived as an answer. If you did not intend this to be an answer to the question please delete it. If you did mean it to be an answer you probably want to readd [answer] and [edit] to get closer to the recommendations there.